# not showing any content in RecyclerView using Fragments and TabLayout

Tags: android

`recycler` view not showing any item, i check the size of adapter its 2 but still not showing ay data in `Recycler` View in Live_Fragment, 
before i use `ListView`, but also it didnt show any item in ListView.
i use the same code in `scoreBoard` first it works fine but when i use 
this in next Fragment in "Live" its didnt show any item neither in `RecyclerView` nor in `List View.`..

**Live_Fragment**

```
    package com.example.admin.cricket_info_5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Live_Fragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Player_Info> batterInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<Player_Info>();
    private String[] name;
    private String[] runs;
    private String[] balls;
    private String[] fours;
    private String[] sixes;
    private String[] runRate;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_fragment, container, false);

        batterInfoArrayList.clear();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.players1);
        runs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.runs1);
        balls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.balls1);
        fours = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fours1);
        sixes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sixes1);
        runRate = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.runRate1);

        for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
            Player_Info batterInfo = new Player_Info(String.valueOf(i+1), name[i], runs[i], balls[i], fours[i], sixes[i], runRate[i]);
            batterInfoArrayList.add(batterInfo);
        }

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter_Player(batterInfoArrayList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter_Player**

```
package com.example.admin.cricket_info_5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Live_Fragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Player_Info> batterInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<Player_Info>();
    private String[] name;
    private String[] runs;
    private String[] balls;
    private String[] fours;
    private String[] sixes;
    private String[] runRate;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_fragment, container, false);

        batterInfoArrayList.clear();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.players1);
        runs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.runs1);
        balls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.balls1);
        fours = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fours1);
        sixes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sixes1);
        runRate = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.runRate1);

        for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
            Player_Info batterInfo = new Player_Info(String.valueOf(i+1), name[i], runs[i], balls[i], fours[i], sixes[i], runRate[i]);
            batterInfoArrayList.add(batterInfo);
        }

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter_Player(batterInfoArrayList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.admin.cricket_info_5;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

//        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Info_Fragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new ScoreBoard_Fragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Live_Fragment();
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return "Info";
                case 1:
                    return "Score Board";
                case 2:
                    return "Live";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

live_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teams"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Pakistan vs India" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bats"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="India is Batting"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:text="Pakistan" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overs"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Overs" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/team"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:text="69-1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balls"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/team"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="15.5" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to `return view;` instead of `inflater.inflate(R.layout.flive_fragment, container, false);` inside `onCreateView()` in your `LiveFragment`